# Finding the Probability of a problem

Tags: probability

Is there anybody that can help me with this question?

What is the chance of winning in a 6/42 lotto draw if you are to bet on 6 combinations?

Comment: Your question isn't clear right now. Do you mean you draw $6$ labelled objects out of a collection of $42$ labelled objects?

Comment: Yeah. That's what I meant to say

Answer (score 1):

The probability of winning with one ticket is $$\frac1{{42\choose6}}=\frac 1{5,245,786}\approx 1.906\times 10^{-7}$$

If you buy $6$ distinct tickets, then your probability of winning with one of them is $$\frac 6{5,245,786}=\frac3{2,622,893}\approx 1.144\times 10^{-6}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you are buying 1 ticket, then $$\frac1 {\binom{42}{6}} \approx 1.906\cdot 10^{-7}$$
Buying 6 tickets and filling them out randomly, independently then the probability that at least one will win is
$$ 1-\bigg(1-\frac{1}{\binom{42}{6}}\bigg)^6 $$
Note: I considered the case when you are to guess 6 number out of 42, and you buy 6 tickets.